# Accessing NSJSONSerialization data using a NSDictionary

Tags: ios, json, serialization

I'm trying to use NSJSONSerialization for retrieving JSON data, the problem is that I can not parse correctly the NSDictionary.

The webservice returns the following:

> [{"Status":"No variables"}]

My code looks like this:

```
...
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://justforexamplepurposes.xyz/file.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@", username, password] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLResponse * response = nil;
NSError * error = nil;
NSData * result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if(error == nil && result != nil)
{
    NSError * json_error = nil;
    id id_json_serialization = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:result options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&json_error];
    if(json_error == nil)
    {
        NSDictionary * dictionary_result = (NSDictionary *) id_json_serialization;
        NSLog(@"|>%@<|", dictionary_result);
        NSEnumerator * enume;
        id key;
        enume = [dictionary_result keyEnumerator];
        while((key =[enume nextObject]))
        {
            NSLog(@"%@ : %@", key, [dictionary_result objectForKey:key]);
        }
    }
}
...
```

The first NSLog is printed correctly:

> |>(
>           {
>           Status = "No variables";
>       } )<|

But at the second NSLog, it throws an Exception:

> 2012-03-17 13:57:22.195 TESTAPP[41072:f803] -[__NSArrayM
>   keyEnumerator]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x689a9f0
>   2012-03-17 13:57:22.196 TESTAPP[41072:f803] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM
>   keyEnumerator]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x689a9f0'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x13e9022 0x157acd6 0x13eacbd 0x134fed0 0x134fcb2 0x2a80 0x13eae99 0x3614e 0x360e6 0xdcade 0xdcfa7 0xdc266
>   0x5b3c0 0x5b5e6 0x41dc4 0x35634 0x12d3ef5 0x13bd195 0x1321ff2
>   0x13208da 0x131fd84 0x131fc9b 0x12d27d8 0x12d288a 0x33626 0x232d
>   0x2295) terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON that the server is returning actually an array with just one object in it. So your variable `dictionary_result` is actually an NSMutableArray.

Quick tip: if you use `CFShow(dictionary_result)` rather than `NSLog(@"|>%@<|", dictionary_result);`, you might have spotted this, as CFShow gives you a lot more information about your object, including type.

Comment: How can I correctly use CFShow(dictionary_result), when I try it, I get the following error "Implicit conversion of Objective-C pointer type 'NSDictionary *' to C pointer type 'CFTypeRef' (aka 'const void *') requires a bridged cast"

Comment: Sorry, you may have to do `CFShow((__bridged CFTypeRef)dictionary_result)`.

Comment: Above comment should be `CFShow((__bridge CFTypeRef)dictionary_result)`, just FYI.